# Retrieve information about the local network

Tags: c, linux, networking, ioctl

I'm writing a library to get information about interfaces presents on a unix machine. To get all the interfaces I use `ioctl` with the `SIOCGIFCONF` request. It returns  in the `ifconf` structure only the interfaces that are currently connected to internet plus the loopback interface.

Does `SIOCGIFCONF` returns only the connected interfaces?

Comment: Not sure about the ioctl but to get the default gateway issue a route -n and you will see your default gateway on the first line(s) with a destination of 0.0.0.0

Comment: I want to do it from c code. Not calling other programs

Comment: Different destinations can have different gateways, even on the same interface.